# msfcli RBreadline and Readline problems

Tags: ruby, metasploit

Hello my friends i have a problem with Metasploit.

OS: Fedora 20
Metasploit: Cloned from git.

The problem is:

when i run

> msfconsole

I have this error:

**"/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)"**

but when i run:

> msfconsole -L

Everithing goes fine.

---

So the issue is that i have to run

> msfcli auxyliary/scanner/smb/smb_enunshares E

**and i get the same error when i run "msfconsole"**

I believe that the problem is for somes GEMS.

---

**EDIT:**

I was able to solve the problem, but this isn't the best way.

I had to modify the code.

This is what i do:

1) edit the file: /metasploit-framework/lib/msf/ui/console/driver.rb
2) go to line: 59
3) replace:

```
    rl = false
rl_err = nil
begin
  if(opts['RealReadline'])
    require 'readline'
    rl = true
  end
rescue ::LoadError
  rl_err = $!
end

# Default to the RbReadline wrapper
require 'readline_compatible' if(not rl)
```

for:

```
rl = true
rl_err = nil
require 'readline'
```

and then everithing should work. What i did is to force the "-L" option in the code.

if anyone have another solution, please post it!

:-)

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? You believe some gems are the problem? Or, the lack of some gems?

Comment: yes i believe that. the problem is the RBreadline library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an incompatibility with Metasploit's bundled rbreadline and ruby 2.x; use 1.9.3 for now or start msfconsole with -L.